# Connecting a 48 V, 12.5 Ah 2C Li-Ion battery (or two in parallel) to a 48 V, 1000 W motor and 1000 W, 40 A controller

Tags: lithium-ion, brushless-dc-motor

I am trying to build an E-Bike that uses a 48 V, 1000 W BLDC Motor with rated current of 35 amps and peak current of 60 amps. I have a Li-Ion battery 48 V, 12.5 Ah with continuous discharge current of 25 amps and peak current of 40 amps. The setup uses a 1000 W, 40 amp rated controller.

Will using a single Li-Ion battery with above capacity damage either the battery or the motor? I wanted to reuse the available battery and buy another one to connect both battery packs in parallel. Is that setup feasible?

Motor Test Parameters for reference:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question: According to those specifications, your motor will likely kill both your controller and your battery, through overload, unless the controller has built-in overload protection, at which point it will instead just stop working when you try to accelerate quickly or go uphill.

When driving motors, you want the driver circuitry to be rated HIGHER than the motor along all axes (voltage, current, power, duty cycle.) You also want the battery to be rated like the controller, not just the motor, for robustness -- sometimes, we bike in the sun, where the ambient temperature is more than the 20 or 25 degrees C assumed in the ratings, for example.

Comment: Thank you Jon. What about adding another pack in parallel to make it effectively 48V 25Ah? Would that work?

Comment: Adding another pack in parallel would help the motor kill the controller faster. You should look for a controller with a rated current (not peak current) above 42.6 Amps, according to that table. And, once the controller is strong enough, yes, you'd need to double the battery pack, or ideally triple it, to avoid overheating it.